# Getting window's properties using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Is there a way to get window's properties like: *title* and *control_type* using pywinauto?

Because it seems that you can search windows by them, but there's no window attribute that points to these properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible through `.element_info` member of wrapper. But there are inconsistencies for some properties. Say you can access `.element_info.name` instead of `.element_info.title`. But `.element_info.control_type` is consistent as well as `.element_info.class_name`.

Will think about aligning them in next release. Thanks for the feedback!